# Did the inventor of the polygraph regret inventing it?

Tags: law-enforcement, lie-detection

In Season 1 Episode 4 of [*Adam Ruins Everything*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Ruins_Everything) Adam Conover says this about [John Augustus Larson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Augustus_Larson) commenting on the [polygraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygraph) machine,

> [Larson] would go on to regret inventing it. Larson became so horrified by law enforcement's unscientific use of his device he would go on to call the machine a *"Frakenstein's Monster."* - Adam Conover, Season 1 Episode 4

So did Larson regret inventing the machine, and did he call it a Frankenstein's Monster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems his source is, [*Truth in the Machine, Three Berkeley men converged to create the lie detector.*](https://alumni.berkeley.edu/california-magazine/spring-2010-searchlight-gray-areas/truth-machine)

> It wasn’t just his protégé he renounced; Larson regretted ever inventing the apparatus. Shortly before his death of a heart attack in 1965, Larson wrote, “Beyond my expectation, thru uncontrollable factors, this scientific investigation became for practical purposes a Frankenstein’s monster, which I have spent over 40 years in combating.”

Also reproduce in Ken Alder's, [*The Lie Detectors: The History of an American Obsession*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QI0S4XhXJ9wC&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=larson+Frankenstein%27s+Monster&source=bl&ots=6LR6S948JS&sig=VDQMlXK9qkH5pv0uxbV5ihUIdCM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD24CasfzSAhUI3mMKHWFnC8cQ6AEITTAM#v=onepage&q=larson%20Frankenstein's%20Monster&f=false)

> Beyond my expectations [...] thru uncontrollable factors, this scientific investigation became for practical purposes a Frankenstein's monster, which I have spent over 40 years in combating.

[New York times repeats a shorter version](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/03/02/books/02book.html) also without providing the original source but in the context of a book review of the *The Lie Detectors* (cited above),

> But toward the end of his life John Larson, inventor of the machine, despaired. He called his work “a Frankenstein’s monster, which I have spent over 40 years in combating.”

I can't find the original source of this claim, or where Larson wrote it.